# Data de concessão de medalha aparece como "Awarded"

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, internacionalização

Mais um bug da série *super simples*:

Ao detalhar uma medalha (por exemplo, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/92/c?userid=2999), na frente da data de concessão aparece como "Awarded".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sugestão: "Concedida".